# I'm looking for a single word to replace a 'lack of response'

Tags: single-word-requests

For example usage, on asking a question.

The lack of response was expected/annoying...

Google gave me 'Indifferent' but I believe there must be something else.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a single word.  Why can't you use "lack of response"? It seems to suit fine in your example.

Comment: @KitFox, in answer to the 'Why' I am interested in increasing my vocabulary. Also I have/had a belief such a word would exist.

Comment: @KitFox in answer to - 'lack of response' seems to suit fine in my example - would this not be the case for many of the single-word-requests on this site? However you may well be right in that those three words are the 'best' to use in my example.

Comment: It wasn't meant as a criticism; I was just wondering if there was some additional context that was missing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Unresponsiveness" works if you really need it to be a single word.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps

> The silence was deafening.

Answer (score 6):

If OP doesn't like **indifference**, how about

> [apathy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/apathy) *- lack of interest or concern, especially regarding matters of general importance or appeal*

Comment: Excellent word **if** the thing in question truly is unresponsive due to apathy. Obviously, it's not an ideal choice if the thing in question isn't apathetic, because you'd be misleading your audience by stating that it is, when perhaps the object is simply unresponsive because of fear or some other motivation.

Comment: Perhaps "apparent apathy" if the person who is offering the point-of-view is unsure as to why the object in question is being unresponsive.

Comment: @Jagd: I must be honest and say that if OP had phrased his question as *"We emailed all our customers asking if they would be interested in an upgrade we're thinking about implementing, but we didn't get any replies. The **xxxx** was expected/annoying". What word/phrase should replace **xxxx** there?*, I doubt I'd have upvoted *anything* except "lack of response". So I don't really think it's a good question anyway.

Answer (score 2):

How about ["non-response"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-response_bias)?  Would that work for what you're doing?

Answer (score 2):

"Inaction", "Inattention", or "Disregard" might be fitting. The first most fitting I think but maybe a little broad.

> The inaction was expected.

Answer (score 2):

*The **stonewalling** was expected/annoying...*

Wikipedia says :

> Stonewalling is a refusal to communicate or cooperate. Such behaviour occurs in situations such as marriage guidance counseling, diplomatic negotiations, politics and legal cases

and *Dictionary.com Unabridged.
Based on the Random House Dictionary* says:

> **stonewalling**
>   noun
>   1.
>   the act of stalling, evading, or filibustering, especially to avoid revealing politically embarrassing information.

—

Answer (score 1):

Consider *[stodginess](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stodginess)* (“state or quality of being stodgy”, *ie* of being dull, old-fashioned); as in “The stodginess of their response shocked me.”  Also consider *[complacency](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/complacency#Noun)*, as in “The complacency of their response amazed me.” Some other words to think about are *[insipidity](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insipidity)*, *[turgidity](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/turgidity)*, *[inertia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inertia)*, and *[Luddism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Luddism)*.

Also consider verb *[cold-shoulder](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cold-shoulder)* (“To disrespect someone, especially by ignoring them”), or noun *[cold shoulder](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cold_shoulder)* (“A deliberate act of disrespect; a slight or snub”),  as in “They cold-shouldered the proposal most obstropulously” or “The cold shoulder was expected but annoying.”  *Slight*, as a  [verb](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slight#Verb) (“To treat as slight or not worthy of attention, to make light of” or “To treat with disdain or neglect”) or  [noun](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slight#Noun) (“The act of slighting; a deliberate act of neglect or discourtesy”), may be used similarly.

Comment: I don't think this is quite what's being asked for. You're describing particular characteristics of an *unhelpful* response (stodgy, complacent, etc.), when what was asked for was a word for no response at all.

Comment: @KellyTessenaKeck, see edit

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the slang office-speak term "crickets".

To *'get crickets'*  during a conference call is to
have asked a question, waited for a response, and heard
only silence.

Example:  *"when the district sales manager called a surprise meeting and asked for feedback, he got only 'crickets'..."*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

> They stayed away in droves.
>
> (attributed to Samuel Goldwyn)